# Concatenation using a mysql variable

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, group-concat

The problem in my query particularly in this piece:

```
@a:= concat(@a, ',', B.call_account_id) AS paid_account_id
```

Here is the whole query:

```
SELECT operator_id, paid_account_ids,  SUM( goods_count * price ) AS sales_volume, count(*) AS sales_cnt
FROM (
    SELECT B.operator_id, @a:= concat(@a, ',', B.call_account_id) AS paid_account_ids, B.call_time, A.goods_count, A.price, UNIX_TIMESTAMP( A.completion_date ) AS paid_ts
    FROM call_module_data B
    INNER JOIN ak_accounts A ON ( A.account_id = B.call_account_id AND A.goods_count >=1 )
    WHERE B.call_status IN (1,7) AND A.status_id = 5
    AND operator_id IN ( $op_ids )
    $and_str_accounts
    GROUP BY A.account_id
    HAVING call_time < (paid_ts + $time_shift)
    ) AS T
GROUP BY operator_id";
```

So the expression mentioned above should produce the concatenated string of account ids (e.g 3341,4355,4433...). But I got NULL instead of desired string. 
Please help to resolve. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have a quote and a semicolon at the end there, that's why it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**GROUP_CONCAT()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function instead of **String concatenation**

Change

```
@a:= concat(@a, ',', B.call_account_id) AS paid_account_id
```

above string to

```
GROUP_CONCAT(B.call_account_id) AS paid_account_ids
```

Final Answer:

```
SELECT operator_id, GROUP_CONCAT(paid_account_ids) AS paid_account_ids, 
       SUM(goods_count * price) AS sales_volume, COUNT(*) AS sales_cnt
FROM (SELECT B.operator_id, GROUP_CONCAT(B.call_account_id) AS paid_account_ids, 
             B.call_time, A.goods_count, A.price, 
             UNIX_TIMESTAMP(A.completion_date) AS paid_ts
      FROM call_module_data B
      INNER JOIN ak_accounts A ON A.account_id = B.call_account_id AND A.goods_count >=1
      WHERE B.call_status IN (1,7) AND A.status_id = 5 AND operator_id IN ($op_ids)
            $and_str_accounts
      GROUP BY A.account_id HAVING call_time < (paid_ts + $time_shift)
     ) AS T
GROUP BY operator_id;
```

Comment: It looks like it should work but I get only first account id instead of concatenated string !?